# Cannot get BootStrap 4 Dropdown to work with my angular application

Tags: html, jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 4, and angular. I have this running in a different application, same setup. I cannot get the dropdown to work in this new application. I have pasted the code below, if anyone can help me see what I am doing wrong that would be appreciated!

```
<div class="dropdown">
   <a class="nav-item nav-link main dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" 
      data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="false" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#dropdown">
    DropdownTitle
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink" id="dropdown">
       <a class="nav-item nav-link my-auto main dropdown-items">dropdown link 1</a>
       <a class="nav-item nav-link my-auto main dropdown-items">dropdown link 2</a>
       <a class="nav-item nav-link my-auto main dropdown-items">dropdown link 3</a>
       <a class="nav-item nav-link my-auto main dropdown-items">dropdown link 4</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

my angular.json file looks like this

```
"styles": 
   [
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
   "styles.css"
   ],
"scripts": 
   [
   "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
   "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
   ]
```

Comment: *I cannot get the dropdown to work*? What isn't working about it?

Comment: Hi, when I click on the main title link “dropdownTitle” nothing happens. If it were working the drop down menu would show the drop down link 1,2,etc.